# RDS database not updating

Tags: mysql, amazon-rds

I have a project with nodejs running on EC2 servers. and RDS for mysql database.
I have two EC2 servers on first EC2(1) server the apis are hosted to serve the apis to the android and IOS apps. On second EC2(2) we have the web panel (admin panel). In some cases the mysql queries fire from the EC2(2) does'nt save into the general log into the RDS. On the other hand from EC2(1) every sql query is saving into the general log. What could be the reason.

Comment: Did you check your mysql logs on EC2(1)?

Comment: actually database is on RDS. and i have enabled the general log on amazon RDS.

Comment: Okay. see all logs inside /var/logs on your ec2. this might give us some clue about the issue.